# AWS Snapshot AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am pretty new to Amazon Web Services. I have launched a non-EBS instance of a server from an AMI and have done some configuration. I want to stop the server now, but I only see options to Reboot and Terminate.

I understand that if I terminate everything is gone. I thought that I could make a "snapshot" of this configuration which could be stored in S3 or something, so that I could later use the snapshot as an AMI and launch that instead.

Obviously I have something wrong - can someone correct me where I am off base? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say, non-EBS, you mean *EC2 instance store-backed* machine. There is no direct menu option provided in AWS console to *snapshot* your instance store machine. This facility you get when you have machine backed by EBS (also, you'd see other convenient options for EBS backed machines).

So, for instance stored backed machines, you need to get your hands dirty. Up your sleeve, here is what you need to do:

1. Create a bucket in S3.
2. Get [`EC2-AMI-Tools`](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/368), and also [`EC2-API-Tools`](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) on your machine/instance. `export` their `bin` folders to your `$PATH`
3. Use `ec2-bundle-volume` to bundle up your instance into a AMI package. (this would not bundle up certain directories, e.g. `/mnt`, `/dev`,...)
4. Upload your bundle to your bucket using `ec2-upload-bundle` command.
5. Then you can register your AMI,using `ec2-register` command.

This AMI is now registered as your private AMI. You can see it in your AWS Web Console under `AMIs`. You can launch this AMI, and it will be in the same state as your instance was, when you created your AMI.

Refer:

- [Amazon guide on how to create AMI](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?creating-an-ami-s3-linux.html)
- [Short and sweet article from RightScale](http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Global/Image_Locator/Actions/Register_an_AMI#Upload_your_AWS.c2.a0key_and_certificate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am running a large instance that will mostly just hold a MySQL database which is relatively small. I will need to make nightly backups. Is using an instance store the "right" approach (I know this is somewhat subjective). Traditionally, the team has made an AMI of the server and kept all of the db data on the `/mnt` drive. Then, they backed up the database to S3.

Comment: @skaz I have configured `MySQL` data directory in a separate EBS volume. If I terminate my machine, my data volume stays. I instanciate a new AMI and "attach" and mount the old volume. If I need to take a snapshot, I will take snapshot of the volume. (I never did though)